# How do I get upcoming appointments in C# from a table in MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I need a way to populate a reminder in my winforms application of appointments that are coming up within the next 15 minutes of a user logging in.  Every SQL query I've tried doesn't give me what I need.  I am a noob, so please don't be too harsh.  I don't have a table that gives me login times, only the appointment table with start date.

> SELECT DISTINCT start FROM appointment  WHERE start < NOW() - INTERVAL
> 15 MINUTE  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM appointment      WHERE start
> = NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your criteria are regarding login time and when you would check, but you need a where clause something like:

```
WHERE start BETWEEN NOW() and NOW() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

Your use of "- INTERVAL 15 MINUTE" is looking in the past, not the future.

Comment: Thanks for that, that query does work, now I just have to figure out what to do in my code when I get those appointments to show the reminder.